# Feature grouping with NestJS

Tags: design-patterns, module, nestjs

We are developing a multi-tenant application but I'm running into a situation where I need to use forwardRef quite often which would indicate a code smell as mentioned in the docs of NestJS. Example of modules in this applications are: app, auth, company, paymet, projectc, survey, search, tenant and user (there are more in reality).

Each module has their own service (aka provider), model, etc. We are using Prisma so we don't have a separate file for the typical crud methods and they are located inside the service itself.

### Example of why forward ref is needed

#### Tenant module

```js
@Module({
    imports: [PaymentModule],
    providers: [TenantService],
})
export class TenantModule {}
```

#### Tenant service

```js
@Injectable()
export class TenantService {
    async get(tenantId: number) {
        return prisma.tenant.findFirst({ where: { id: tenantId } });
    }

    async create(data) {
        // ... logic
        const tenantId = generateId();
        await PaymentService.createCustomer(tenantId)
        // ... logic
    }
}
```

#### Payment module

```js
@Module({
    imports: [TenantModule],
    providers: [PaymentService],
})
export class PaymentModule {}
```

#### Payment service

```js
@Injectable()
export class PaymentService {
    async createCustomer(tenantId) {
        // ... logic
    }

    async charge(tenantId: number) {
        const tenant = await this.tenantService.get(tenantId);
        // ... logic
    }
}
```

## Question

My question is how should we adjust our structure to be more "feature grouping". Currently for example we are using the tenant service in a lot of the other modules and I don't see how it would be a "feature". Any guidance, tips, links, documents that would help are highly welcome. I don't really see another way of doing this and can't find good examples either.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably have another module that handles your logic.

We could imagine a SuperFunctionnalityModule, with its own controller/service that would look likes this, following your code:

```
//...correct class declaration
async createTenantForFunctionnality(data) {        
    const tenantId = TenantService.generateId();
    await PaymentService.createCustomer(tenantId)
    
}
```

Thus, each service only deals with its own logic, and your functionality/app-related module bootstraps it all.

Also, some modules might be declared/register globally (see https://docs.nestjs.com/modules#global-modules), its probably the case for your auth module.